# Route Internet traffic to Azure site-to-site VPN tunnel on Sonicwall TZ205

Tags: routing, azure, sonicwall, site-to-site-vpn, virtual-network

I have configured Sonicwall TZ205 a [Route-Based VPN](https://support.software.dell.com/download/downloads?id=5348068) which connect to a dynamic gateway on Windows Azure VNet. The site-to-site VPN connection is established successfully. The machines in on-premise network and the VNet are able to communicate. The Internet traffic is routed to the ISP gateway and the LAN traffic is routed to the IPSec VPN tunnel.

The on-premise network is in China, the users in the network are not able to access the censored websites. I would like to route the Internet traffic of an IP range to the IPSec VPN tunnel so that the user can access censored websites via Windows Azure VNet gateway. For example, allow 192.168.1.2~192.168.1.20 internet traffic to be routed to the VPN tunnel instead of ISP gateway.

I read through the [user manual of Sonicwall TZ205](https://support.software.dell.com/download/downloads?id=6054217) but I am not able to find a clue on how to do this.

Can anyone give me some idea if this is something can be done ? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Looks like this is something cannot be done yet : http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28694774/Routing-on-premises-internet-traffic-through-existing-Azure-VPN-and-virtual-network.html

Comment: Yeah, it can't be done at the moment. Your best bet is to setup a proxy server (Squid?) in your Azure VNet that your users in China can reach through the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to allow the tunnel from your internal network as source and destination would be the entire Internet,  0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 & ::/0

Enable remote network add default gateway.